# Google Slide Transistion Animations not working properly

Tags: google-workspace, google-slides-api

I am trying to make object animate one after another using the animate AFTER previous object
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiuL0.png)

When I play animations, they all appear at the same time. I do not see where I can adjust the time between each object appearing so I assume it is set for 0.

This is a slide I created. I am a teacher.

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Dr1Ie6PQUsrS8KlfpQQDiAezv4hXcP3W_c1sNUEo9co/edit?usp=sharing

I want the 4 boxes to appear 1 after another WITH OUT ME having to click for each one to show which would allow students to count them as they appear. I want the same with the apples. I want them to appear 1 after another without me having to click for each one to appear.  I was able to do this option with no problem last school year. There use to be a timer bar under for me to pick how many seconds before the object would appear and now I see none.